# Jekyll powered site - amount of text shown on homepage

Tags: ruby, html, jekyll

I am setting my blog up using the fantastic Jekyll. Question is my markdown files are being shown in full on the homepage. How do i make them look more like this? So that only a little bit comes up with the title? 
Thanks.

http://daverupert.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT: As of Jekyll 1.0, this is not longer necessary (Answer is outdated).**

Jekyll 1.0 exports a `post.excerpt` variable that contains the first paragraph of a post by default.

**/Edit**

So, you want to show an excerpt of the post, instead of the full post?

Theres three ways to do that:

- Render the full post but use CSS to hide everything that is not needed
- Use filters. You can access `post.content`, use the `truncate` filter to truncate it and the `markdownify` filter to render it.
- Specify the excerpt in YAML Front Matter and render it using `{{post.excerpt | markdownify}}` (that is what i do on my blog)

Comment: The last point looks like the right way to do it to me. So in my default.html layout file i need to add in  {{post.excerpt | markdownify}}

Comment: Great answer. Minor point in your #2 way: I believe post.content is already converted to html by the time the filter runs.  This is unfortunate since truncate will likely lose some html closing tag.

Answer (score 0):

Each of those blocks between horizontal lines are links to the actual blog post. Any time I have a question about how someone did something on their webpage I always view-source.

The source for that page is -
view-source:http://daverupert.com/

To find out how to do something in markdown I like this site -
http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/basics

Comment: That doesn't work with Jekyll as it works in the same way as scss does with css. You can't see how something is actually been built.